# XMPPFramework for iOS, didReceiveTrust implementation

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

i'm trying to implement simple didReceiveTrust in `XMPPStreamDelegate`, but Xcode shows warning on method definition:

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceiveTrust trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: XMPPStreamCompletionHandler) {
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

warning is following:

> Instance method
>   'xmppStream(sender:didReceiveTrust:completionHandler:)' nearly matches
>   optional requirement 'xmppStream(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)' of
>   protocol 'XMPPStreamDelegate'

when testing app i'm getting following in output:

> 2018-06-12 23:10:11:239 MyMessages[55145:3561831] XMPPStream: Stream
>   secured with (GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust == YES), but there
>   are no delegates that implement
>   xmppStream:didReceiveTrust:completionHandler:. This is likely a
>   mistake.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following function definition works as expected:

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream?, didReceive trust: SecTrust?, completionHandler: @escaping (_ shouldTrustPeer: Bool) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

Comment: Can you add some context / explanation to make your answer better understandable for others?